# Bootstrap 2 columns center headline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have a "header" which is class `.row` and two columns with classes `.col-md-2` and `.col-md-10`. In the first column there is the logo and in the second the page-heading.

I created a fiddle for you: http://www.bootply.com/TXG3QC7TNo

How can I overlap two columns so that the heading is really centered not only in the column? I tried it with positions (header - relative and columns - absolute) but it breaks the responsiveness!

Answer (score 2):

U can do it in one `<div>`:

```css
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Logo"><h1 class="text-center">Test</h1></div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

AND give ur

> `img{position:absolute;}`

so you won't loose ur responsibility

Comment: I tried this to - but it will be displayed in two rows. One with the Image and one with the headline

Comment: arr my bad :P, u can give the `img{position:absolute;}`

Comment: Thanks :) It's working - I tried and searched for about 3 hours :/ ^^

Answer (score 0):

The h1 tag is a block-level element, try adding 'display:inline-block' to it.